# How do I zoom in with my bow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've started playing Skyrim again after a few months and am having some trouble with archery. I've got the Eagle Eye perk, which says I can zoom in by holding the Block button. However, I'm not sure what the Block button is. I've never used a shield in this character's life so I've never had reason to try to block before.

It seems either I'm not quite doing this right, or I've got the block button remapped to an unknown key. In the Settings, however, I don't see anywhere that you can set which key to bind "Block" to, so I don't know how to check if I've remapped it.

So:

1. What do you need to do to zoom in your bow?
2. How can I check which key I've got Block mapped to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Block button is the Left Hand action, which is, by default, the M2 (right) mouse button. You can check what the Left Hand action is mapped to in the Controls section of the main menu (<kbd>Esc</kbd>).

The assigned button/key should zoom in the bow when pressed once you've started to draw the arrow, as illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: zoomed in bow]

If you haven't drawn an arrow yet, pressing the Block button will cause you to thrust your bow out in front of you in a bashing motion. If you haven't yet unlocked the Eagle Eye skill, pressing the Block button with an arrow drawn will simply not do anything.

Searching around suggests that a handful or so of people have had a problem where despite having the Eagle Eye perk, pressing the Block button with an arrow drawn doesn't have the expected outcome. This may be because the perk hasn't been applied correctly for some reason. If this happens to you, and you're willing to resort to console commands, you could try removing and reapplying the perk by typing the following:

```
~
player.removeperk 00058f61
player.addperk 00058f61
```

Failing this, you can also try resetting your bindings to the default values by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> on the Controls screen, although I'm not sure if this would have any impact.

Comment: I guess the third possibility is that [my game is glitched](http://www.gameskyrim.com/eagle-eye-not-working-t163309.html), since this sounds like I'm trying the correct procedure. I'd done some pretty extensive key remapping initially and it may have caused issues.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like something's a bit messed up unfortunately. I updated the answer with two suggestions to that effect, but admittedly I'm not confident they'll do much for you. :/

Comment: Alright, so this is rather embarrassing to admit, but it turns out I didn't actually have the perk. Like I said, it had been a while since I played, and I thought blue dots were perks I had, not gold dots. Doh. Going to clean up the question a bit to remove my stupidity since it's still a valid question and answer.

Comment: Where do you get those arrows?

Comment: @garrett They're glass arrows; I believe you typically find them killing Dwarven Centurions and the like.